# Confusion with balls in general metric spaces.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

My teacher gave during a lecture the definition of a ball(closed) as this:
$$B(x,r) = {y\in \Re^{n}, \left \| x-y \right \|<r }$$

Then he proceeded to give an example:

for $$\left \| \cdot  \right \|_{2}$$ we have : $$B_{2}(0,1) = {((x,y)\in \Re ), \sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}}<1}$$

Which confuses me a bit. In the example, $x=0$, so if we replace the x by $0$ in the definition we should get this:
$$B_{2}(0,1) = {((x,y)\in \Re ), \sqrt{0^{2}+y^{2}}<1}$$ which gives us
$$B_{2}(0,1) = {((x,y)\in \Re ), \sqrt{y^{2}}<1}$$
Which is quite different from what the teacher gave us.

I find it confusing because, in the definition the only free variable is $y$, and $x$ is set. Yet in the example both are free.

Comment: Yeah I'm not a fan of your teacher's notation. I prefer this definition: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ball_(mathematics)#Balls_in_general_metric_spaces

Comment: Using the notation in the wikipedia, it makes much more sense. Yet, I don't understand the logic of my teacher. He sets a specific value to x, how can it be a free afterwards? Is this notation even used anywhere?

Comment: Maybe he has some reasoning behind it or you misunderstood. Double-check in office hours? But in general, people use weird notation. Disregard their notation, make sure to understand the concept, and use better, more accessible notation. If you use Wikipedia's notation, he will surely understand.

Comment: His notation made me very confused and unable to understand the concept. I will go ahead and ask him about this. I had a prior understanding of this concept, yet when seeing this notation and example, my understanding went at stake.

Comment: If in doubt, just remember that a ball has a center at $(x,y)$ or $(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ in $R^n$, and is the set of points that are less than a distance of $r$ from that center, using whatever distance metric you have defined on that space.

Comment: The $0$ in $B_2(0,1)$ is the additive-identity vector of the vector space $\mathbb R^2$, not the number $0$. It is a common "abuse of notation" to call it $0$. Strictly speaking, we should write $B_2((0,0),1).$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the definition of $B(x, r)$, it is given that $x\in \Re^n$ and $r>0$ is a real number. So when your teacher writes $B_2(0, 1)$, it is understood that $0$ corresponds to an elements in $\Re ^2$. Very likely by $0$ your teacher denotes the zero vector $\vec 0 = (0,0)$ in $\Re^2$ (instead of $\Re$!). (Like it or not, this abuse of notation is rather common, just that it becomes a bit annoying in this situation). Thus by definition,

$$B_2(\vec 0, 1) = \{\vec v = (x, y) \in \Re^2 : \| \vec v - \vec 0\|<1\}.$$
The equation is the same as 
$$ \sqrt{(x-0)^2 + (y-0)^2} <1.$$

Also, please check with the teacher concerning the term closed: in all texts on metric spaces I've seen, one use $\le $ instead of $<$ (which corresponds to open balls).